# Gaining Focus on <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have 2 canvases, to display the front and back of a shirt respectively. I have used a list to select whether I want to display the front or the back. I can only solve the problem with an anchor (`#front`), but it will mean scrolling to that specific location in the webpage. Do I have other methods to implement it and set focus to the front canvas when the page loads?

```
<ul style="border:0px solid yellow; padding-left:10px;">
    <li id="One">
        <a href="#One" id="first" style="height:20px; width:208px; margin-bottom:-8px; padding-bottom:0px;">
            <span style="margin-left:15px; font-size:medium;">Front Side</span>
        </a>
        <div>
            <canvas id="collage" width="450" height="450" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Two">
        <a href="#Two" id="sec" style="height:20px; width:208px; margin-bottom:-8px; padding-bottom:0px;">
            <span style="margin-left:15px; font-size:medium;">Back Side</span>
        </a>
        <div>
            <canvas id="collage2" width="450" height="450" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the canvas a tab index:

```
<canvas 
    id="collage" 
    width="450" 
    height="450" 
    style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" 
    tabindex="1">
</canvas>
```

and then call `document.getElementById('collage').focus()`

EDIT: Aside from 'focussing' if the issue is simulating a click on and a href on page load, you could do the following with jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#One').click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: this didn't work, I added <script>document.getElementById('collage').focus();</script> but it still displays nothing.

Comment: Well this would be how you 'focus' the canvas element, perhaps you could elaborate on what you mean by 'focus'?

Comment: by the code above, it only shows me the 2 tabs for me to select the front and back canvas. When i load a fresh page, no canvas are displayed and I must manually click on a tabto display a canvas. I am trying to eliminate the manual click and display the canvas straightaway..

Comment: I placed the ready function code into a <script> tag, but it still doesn't do anything.. Only thing that work is if i used an anchor for page load in the url.. Is there anything i am missing out?

Comment: You'd need to make sure you include a reference to jQuery for that to work such as '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>'

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function focuscanvas() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myGame');
        canvas.focus();
    };
</script>
```

Use this as `onclick` event whenever you need to focus on canvas.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="focuscanvas()" >
    Focus on Collage
</button>
```